# Setting listcells in a loop of cases

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm trying to create a loop, but my "list cells" instead of count the 19 cells that are currently located by the following script, the loop shows me around 40 results. I appreciate your help.

```
Sub test6()
Dim SingleCell, Listcells As Range

Workbooks("OLD CAD").Sheets("Contract History-Modifications").Range("B:B").Find(" CM Name/Number", MatchCase:=True).Select
Range(ActiveCell.Address).Offset(2, 0).Select
Range(ActiveCell.Address, Range(ActiveCell.Address).End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Offset(0, 13).Activate
Set Listcells = Selection

For Each SingleCell In Listcells
            Select Case True
                Case Is = InStr(1, (SingleCell.Value), "Yes") > 0
                    MsgBox (SingleCell.Value)

                Case Else
                    MsgBox ("F")
    End Select
Next SingleCell

End Sub
```

Comment: 2 things, variable `SingleCell` is not a range although you might think it is. Add `ListCells.Count` to see how many cells your code is picking up.

Comment: Is your data filtered?

Comment: Hi, the msgbox ListCells.Count said 20.

So in case of the SingleCell do I need to erase from the Dim?

Comment: Nope, the info isn't filtered. But my idea is to use that script in different files so the location and the row.count would be different.

Comment: They are just pointing out that in VBA you must declare the type of each individual variable (`Dim a As X, b As X`) - if you do `Dim a, b As X` then `a` is a Variant not type X.

Comment: Something I didn't mention because I figured out right now is that my destination column is merged, so I think that the result of the cases is showing me the result from the column1 and column2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for select/activate:

```
Sub test6()

    Dim c as range, Listcells As Range, ws As Worksheet, f as range

    Set ws = Workbooks("OLD CAD").Sheets("Contract History-Modifications") 'should also add the file extension
    Set f = ws.Range("B:B").Find(" CM Name/Number", MatchCase:=True)

    If not f is nothing then
        Set ListCells = ws.Range(f, f.End(xlDown))
        For each c in ListCells.Cells

            Debug.Print c.address, IIf(Instr(c.value, "Yes") > 0, c.value, "F")

        Next c
    else
        Debug.Print "not found!"
    end if

End Sub
```